# Web scraping. in Python how can I operate with active links?

Tags: python, hyperlink, reference, web-scraping

I use BeautifulSoup for web scraping.
So I need to analyse this table: [Google Finance](https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3AAAPL&fstype=ii&ei=JQHoWMjKCcjDsAHAhqS4DA)
As you can see there are "Annual Data" and "Quarterly Data". When I extract table python returns just quarterly data but I have no idea how to extract annual. Does anybody know? 
Below is HTML code that represents this link.

```html
<div class="g-unit g-first">
View:
<a id="interim" class="id-interim nac" target="_blank">Quarterly Data</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a id="annual" class="id-annual ac" target="_blank">Annual Data</a>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'Param': ['Total Revenue', 'Cost of revenue', 'Gross profit', 
                      'Operating expenses','Research Development'],
             '2016': [123, 234343, 3423, 343, 323],
             '2015': [3432423, 2342, 2342342, 356856, 36934],
             '2014': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73],
             '2013': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73]}

url = 'https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3AAAPL&fstype=ii&ei=JQHoWMjKCcjDsAHAhqS4DA'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
raw_df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Param', '2016', '2015', '2014','2013'])

# Find all the <tr> tag pairs, skip the first one, then for each.

for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    col = row.find_all('td')
    column_1 = col[0].string.strip()
    Revenue.append(column_1)

    column_2 = col[1].string.strip()
    _2016_.append(column_2)

    column_3 = col[2].string.strip()
    _2015_.append(column_3)

    column_4 = col[3].string.strip()
    _2014_.append(column_4)

    column_5 = col[4].string.strip()
    _2013_.append(column_5)

columns = {'In Millions of USD': Revenue, '52 weeks ending 2016': _2016_, '52 weeks ending 2015': _2015_, '52 weeks ending 2014': _2014_, '52 weeks ending 2013': _2013_}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns)
```

Comment: pls share your code to us. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Done

Comment: @PiskarevDmitry, have you tried using Developer tools to get the request being sent when you move from quaterly to annual under network tab, especially see the different headers sent along with it, You need to set the referer and other headers as required to get the data you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working but I got an idea of what you really want.
You want to scrape the table for annual data into a panda dataframe.
Hope this helps.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

params, _2016_, _2015_, _2014_, _2013_ = [], [], [], [], []
url = 'https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3AAAPL&fstype=ii&ei=JQHoWMjKCcjDsAHAhqS4DA'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
#print(soup)                                             #to get an idea on the class id
table = soup.find("div", {"class": "id-incannualdiv"})   #this is the table for annual data report
rows = [t.text for t in table.find_all("td")]            #get all rows then convert rows into columns
i=0
for r in rows:
    if i%5 == 0:
        params.append(r.rstrip("\r\n"))
    if i%5 == 1:
        _2016_.append(r)
    if i%5 == 2:
        _2015_.append(r)
    if i%5 == 3:
        _2014_.append(r)
    if i%5 == 4:
        _2013_.append(r)
    i+=1
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(params, _2016_, _2015_, _2014_, _2013_)), \
 columns=['In Millions of USD', '52 weeks ending 2016', '52 weeks ending 2015', '52 weeks ending 2014', '52 weeks ending 2013'])
df.head()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add tables array as having both annual,quart data tables

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'Param': ['Total Revenue', 'Cost of revenue', 'Gross profit', 
                      'Operating expenses','Research Development'],
             '2016': [123, 234343, 3423, 343, 323],
             '2015': [3432423, 2342, 2342342, 356856, 36934],
             '2014': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73],
             '2013': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73]}

url = 'https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3AAAPL&fstype=ii&ei=JQHoWMjKCcjDsAHAhqS4DA'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
raw_df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Param', '2016', '2015', '2014','2013'])
Revenue,_2016_,_2015_,_2014_,_2013_=[],[],[],[],[]
# Find all the <tr> tag pairs, skip the first one, then for each.
table=soup.find_all('table')[1:3]
for tab in table:
    for row in tab.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        col = row.find_all('td')
        column_1 = col[0].string.strip()
        Revenue.append(column_1)

        column_2 = col[1].string.strip()
        _2016_.append(column_2)

        column_3 = col[2].string.strip()
        _2015_.append(column_3)

        column_4 = col[3].string.strip()
        _2014_.append(column_4)

        column_5 = col[4].string.strip()
        _2013_.append(column_5)

columns = {'In Millions of USD': Revenue, '52 weeks ending 2016': _2016_, '52 weeks ending 2015': _2015_, '52 weeks ending 2014': _2014_, '52 weeks ending 2013': _2013_}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns)
```